# How to enable mysql strict mode globally and have it stay on?

Tags: mysql, strict

How do I enable MySQL strict mode globally, and have it stay on?

I have tried these commands:

```
SET sql_mode = TRADITIONAL;
SET sql_mode = ANSI_QUOTES;
```

But they only set the mode for the current session.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: Setting sql\_mode permanently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20373532/mysql-setting-sql-mode-permanently)

Answer (score 1):

To set the SQL mode at server startup, use:
- the `--sql-mode="modes"` option on the command line, or
- `sql-mode="modes"` in an option file such as `my.cnf` (Unix operating systems) or my.ini (Windows). ("modes" is a list of different modes separated by commas.)

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html