# MySQL: Setting sql_mode permanently

Tags: mysql, sql-mode

Via the MySQL command line client, I am trying to set the global mysql_mode:

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = TRADITIONAL;
```

This works for the current session, but after I restart the server, the sql_mode goes back to its default: '', an empty string.

How can I permanently set sql_mode to TRADITIONAL?

If relevant, the MySQL is part of the WAMP package.

Thank you.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Add this to your my.cnf file (or my.ini if you're using windows):

```
sql_mode="TRADITIONAL"
```

and restart the server

Comment: I added sql-mode="TRADITIONAL" in my my.ini file, under "socket  = /tmp/mysql.sock", and now the MySQL command line client won't start.

Comment: Nevermind I got it. I added under [client] instead of [wampmysqld]. Thank you for this, I will accept your answer and upvote you by one point in accordance with the stackoverflow friendly exchange policy.

Comment: I was going to suggest you edit to the now used sql_mode instead of sql-mode, but alas my edit must be 6 chars. Perhaps this did or does apply to some version of MySQl or deployment of it, but not the latest.

Comment: @bitsum As far as I know it doesn't matter if you write it with a dash or an underscore. And I'm not aware, that this behaviour was changed in any version or that a certain style is dependent on a certain version.

Comment: Well I say this because I used a dash at first, following this article, but when I pulled the latest update, it error'd on me until I replaced that dash with an underscore. So, it may now apply. Of course, this is under Ubuntu and MySql 5.7, so who knows on Windows.

Comment: On debian jessie this was found in /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

Comment: How can this be done under Win10? See my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75766115/mysql-setting-sql-mode-permanently-under-windows-10)

Answer (score 36):

MySQL sql_mode `"TRADITIONAL"`, a.k.a. "strict mode", is defined by [the MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html) as:

> “give an error instead of a warning” when inserting an incorrect value into a column.

Here's how to ensure that your sql_mode is set to `"TRADITIONAL"`.

**First, check your current setting:**

```
mysql
mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
+-------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.sql_mode |
+-------------------+
|                   |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This returned blank, the default, that's bad: your sql_mode is not set to "TRADITIONAL".

**So edit the configuration file:**

```
sudo vim /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Add this line in the section labelled `[mysqld]`: `sql_mode="TRADITIONAL"` (as fancyPants pointed out)

**Then restart the server:**

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

**Then check again:**

```
mysql
mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.sql_mode                                                                                                                                    |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,STRICT_ALL_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,TRADITIONAL,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Success!  You are golden now.

Comment: how about if i want to turn it off permanently sql-mode="" does not work

Comment: @dragonfire it's `sql_mode` not `sql-mode`.  I just tried it now and setting `sql_mode = ""` and restarting the server works to clear all the settings.

Answer (score 0):

For mysql8 on windows:

```
# Set the SQL mode to strict
sql-mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

It's a dash, not an underscore: sql_mode / sql-mode

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Digital Ocean**, the mysql `cnf` files are emulated and don't actually really interact with the database.  In this case, you set your sql-mode with (for a blank sql mode)...

```
doctl databases sql-mode set DB-UUID ""
```

If you don't know your DB UUID, check it out with:

```
GET DB UUID with: doctl databases list
```

Source: [digitalocean.com: doctl databases sql-mode set](https://docs.digitalocean.com/reference/doctl/reference/databases/sql-mode/set/)