# How to fix error SQL_MODE on Mac

Tags: mysql, macos

I have install MySQl on my iMAC. So when I try to run my java application, I have this error

> ....which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

To fixed it, I start mysql from terminal, then I write this command

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';
SET SESSION sql_mode = '';
```

I launch these command on terminal then I can start my application never error.
So if I restart my PC, I have the same error. There is a property that I can set and then I don't must re-change it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: Setting sql\_mode permanently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20373532/mysql-setting-sql-mode-permanently)

Comment: put the setting in the my.cnf