# How to set the password admin to the user root in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have tried something shown below :

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'validate_password%';
```

The output should be something like that :

```
+--------------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                        | Value |
+--------------------------------------+-------+
| validate_password.check_user_name    | ON    |
| validate_password.dictionary_file    |       |
| validate_password.length             | 6     |
| validate_password.mixed_case_count   | 1     |
| validate_password.number_count       | 1     |
| validate_password.policy             | LOW   |
| validate_password.special_char_count | 1     |
+--------------------------------------+-------+
```

then you can set the password policy level lower, for example:

```
SET GLOBAL validate_password.length = 6;

SET GLOBAL validate_password.number_count = 0;
```

The problem is when I set the fields and then restart mysql it again setted to default.
I have also tried,

```
mysql> flush priviledges;
```

Please help me how can I set the password of my user **root** to the **admin**.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. You are describing a problem that you cannot save server variables, but you are asking how to set the password for a user. These are different problems/questions. Do you want to change the password of a user or do you want to know how to set system configuration variables persistently for a MySQL server?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL: Setting sql\_mode permanently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20373532/mysql-setting-sql-mode-permanently)

Answer (score 2):

You should set up your settings in a configuration file `my.cnf`.

Check this article for proper path depending on a system you use.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html