# Setting sql_mode permanently under Windows 10

Tags: mysql

After updating to MySQL 8.0.32 under Windows 10 I would like to permanently switch off ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY in "sql_mode". *SET GLOBAL sql_mode='...'* is not permanent and the default setting, which includes ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, is reestablished after every service shutdown/restart.
So I looked for the config file. Executing `>mysqladmin` I read

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
C:\WINDOWS\my.ini C:\WINDOWS\my.cnf C:\my.ini C:\my.cnf C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.cnf,
```

but none of these files exists in my system. So I created the file
`C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.cnf` with the following contents:

```
[mysqld]

sql_mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

but after restarting the service a *SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;* included ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY as usual.

I renamed `my.cnf` to `my.ini` and used other directories for the file, then I replaced in the file `[mysqld]` by `[client]` or `sql_mode` by `sql-mode` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20373532/mysql-setting-sql-mode-permanently)
but to no avail.

Comment: `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY ` is enabled by default for a very good reason (to prevent _meaningless_ query results) - you don't need to disable the option to use functional-dependency-detection in MySQL 8 either, so why do you want to disable it?

Comment: @Dai _Why do you want to disable it?_ Because updating legacy code isn't done in a minute.

Comment: ...but your legacy code is returning bogus results :S Arguably an error message is _better_

Comment: With `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` our system was partly unusable, as some queries were simply rejected. Since in the past years no erroneous results were discovered, we decided to run in the old mode for a while. Now, updating our code has been done and we run the system with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` set.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the definition of sql-mode in %PROGRAMDATA%\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini did the job.

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem after reinstalling.

All ways mentioned, doesn't fix...when reading the sql-mode with the select command, it always shows the same.

Only works, for the session, to edit the value via phpMyadmin.

Keep looking for a solution.

Comment: What OS are you running?

Answer (score 0):

When the MySQL server is in ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode, all columns in the SELECT clause that are not in an aggregate function (such as SUM, AVG, MIN, MAX, GROUP_CONCAT, etc.) are required to be included in the GROUP BY clause or in an aggregation function.

For example, if you have a query like this:

SELECT column1, column2, AVG(column3)
FROM table
GROUP BY column1;

This query will fail in ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode because column2 is not in the GROUP BY clause or an aggregation function.

To fix this, you can add column2 to the GROUP BY clause:

SELECT column1, column2, AVG(column3)
FROM table
GROUP BY column1, column2;

Or you can use an aggregation function on column2:
SELECT column1, MAX(column2), AVG(column3)
FROM table
GROUP BY column1;

In summary, to avoid errors when MySQL server is in ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode, make sure that all columns in your SELECT clause are in the GROUP BY clause or in an aggregation function.