# Making sql_mode permanent in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, sql-mode

Every reboot, the STRICT_TRANS_TABLES gets added to sql_mode. I have to go to phpmyadmin and remove it under Variables.  I have tried to change it using SQL commands but it doesn't seem to survive a server reboot.

There are [existing answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20373532/mysql-setting-sql-mode-permanently) to this question, but they appear to be dated.  I am using MariaDB version **10.5.21-MariaDB-0+deb11u1** on **Debian 11** and **Apache 2.4.56**.  I also looked at the [MariaDB sql_mode documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-mode/) but there is no mention of where to change sql_mode permanently.

Based on my searches I would expect it to be in /etc/mysql/my.cnf but it appears that MariaDB now does things differently.  The my.cnf contains:

```
[client-server]
# Port or socket location where to connect
# port = 3306
socket = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Import all .cnf files from configuration directory
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
```

so I examined each file in the above two directories, but no luck.  I even tried grepping in case I missed it visually:

```
 sudo grep -rnw '/etc/mysql/conf.d/' -e 'sql_mode'
 sudo grep -rnw '/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/' -e 'sql_mode'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

`STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` is part of the [default sql_mode](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#sql_mode).

To make it permanent, you need to add it to a configuration file like.

/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/general.cnf:

```
[mariadb]
sql_mode=ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY
```

Comment: There is no such file and there isn't any reference to such a file in the my.cnf file.

Comment: You have the power to create files with arbitary contents right? Listing all the available options in any configuration file would be excessively verbose.

Comment: So I need to create a /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/general.cnf file?  I don't have a lot of leeway to test various options since it is a production server.